# Concat list of dataframes and merge by index to separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate a list of dataframes. However, I also want to use the list index of each dataframe so I can do a cross join from a separate dataframe.

To illustrate:

dfA

```
    A    B 
0   A0   B0
1   A1   B1
```

dfB

```
    A    B 
0   A2   B2
1   A3   B3
2   A4   B4
```

dfC

```
    A    B 
0   A5   B5
1   A6   B6
```

dfcross

```
    C    D 
0   C0   D0
1   C1   D1
2   C2   D2
```

**Intended join output**

```
    A    B    C    D 
0   A0   B0   C0   D0
1   A1   B1   C0   D0
2   A2   B2   C1   D1
3   A3   B3   C1   D1
4   A4   B4   C1   D1
5   A5   B5   C2   D2
6   A6   B6   C2   D2
```

code would be something like this:

```
import pandas ad pd
dfA= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1']})
dfB= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A2', 'A3','A4'], 'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B4']})
dfA= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A5', 'A6'], 'B': ['B5', 'B6']})

dfcross= pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2'], 'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2']})

dfconcat = pd.concat([dfA,dfB,dfC])
dfconcat.join(dfcross)
```

Comment: why do you expect the last row to be filled by C1 and D1? the last tow has index 2 for dfconcat which isnot present in dfC

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question oddly, I want to join each row from dfC to map to each listed dataframe

Comment: what you said is a cartesian join and can be achieved by `dfconcat.assign(k=1).merge(dfC.assign(k=1),on='k').drop('k',1)` but I am still unclear on how you want the join

Comment: Edited question, this may be a cross/cartesian join like you say

Comment: Quick typo question: Second dfA is supposed to be dfC?

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
dfD =  pd.concat([dfA, dfB])
dfD = pd.concat([dfD, dfC], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Do not know if this is what you want

Comment: raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects